# silly file reading question for new python user

Tags: python, string, path, escaping

I am simply trying to define a path and file name then use `pandas.read_csv()`
in the variable `display` of *spyder*, the `path` and `file name` appear correct, but in reality they have double `\\`.  I know this has got to be something really stupid...

```
siteinfopath=r'C:\Users\cpsei\Documents'
siteinfofile=siteinfopath+'\grav_stats.csv'
grav_stats=pd.read_csv(siteinfofile)
```

When i run the script I get the following error message:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File
>   b'C:\Users\cpsei\Documents\grav_stats.csv' does not exist:
>   b'C:\Users\cpsei\Documents\grav_stats.csv'

and when I type

```
siteinfofile
Out[145]: 'C:\\Users\\cpsei\\Documents\\grav_stats.csv'
```

Why the double `\`. In the variable `viewer` the path is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You see double `\\` instead of one, because `\` is used in python as **escape character** - it informs that this `\` character and next character should be threated in special way. For example:

- `\t` - means `TAB`
- `\r` - is *carriage return* - cursor moves to the beginning of the line
- `\n` - is *new line* - cursor moves to beginning of new line

If however you want just plain simple `\`, you have to use `\\` - first one informs as usual that there is some special character, and next informs that this special character is actually `\`.

You can read more about it ie on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings - there is a lot of very good examples :)

So, everything is OK, your strings work as expected. If you want to see how this string looks like, and not how it is constructed, `print` it:

```
>>> print(siteinfofile)
C:\Users\cpsei\Documents\grav_stats.csv
```

Are you sure path is correct and you can read this file? That's the only advice I can think of here...